# SSH fails to connect from Raspberry Pi to Mac laptop

Tags: macos, networking, ssh

I've got two machines on a local network, a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian wheezy, and a Macbook Air running OS X 10.8.5. I'm trying to set things up so I can ssh freely back and forth between the two machines.

Going from the Macbook to the Pi is fine, no problem. However, when I try to connect from the Pi back to the Macbook, the `ssh` command hangs for a few minutes, then times out.

There's definitely a working `sshd` on the Mac, as I can happily do `ssh localhost`. I can also see packets from the Pi if I attempt the connection while running `sudo tcpdump host raspberrypi.local and port 22`. Running the `ssh` command under `strace` shows it hanging at the `connect()` syscall. I've tried increasing the `sshd` log level to `DEBUG3`, but I see nothing in the logs to indicate that the connection even makes it as far as `sshd`.

As far as I can tell, the problem is unique to this Macbook. When I try with another (borrowed) laptop, I can connect to/from the Raspberry Pi, but have the same problem when connecting to the original Macbook.

Other services on the Macbook (webserver, etc) are apparently unaffected. It also makes no difference whether I use IP addresses or hostnames. Just in case, I've disabled reverse DNS in `sshd_config`, but to no avail.

What are my next steps to debug this? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Firewall is enabled on the mac?

Comment: Sounds a lot like some kind of "allowed hosts" issue on the MacBook itself. I've encountered similar issues, and my own fixes involved removing/uninstalling my antivirus program at the time (which was hard blocking any and all remote login attempts). I might also recommend trying to do your ssh from your Raspberry Pi with the -vvv flag, to get the verbose debug information. Might steer you in the right direction.

Comment: No firewall, not as far as I can tell. As for the -vvv flag, that just shows the "Connecting to laptop.local" line, which seems to indicate the same thing as strace - it's trying and failing to open the TCP connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was that although the system firewall was disabled, some rules still remained in `ipfw`. Running `sudo ipfw flush` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled sharing:

To enable it, go to ‘System Preferences’. 'Click Sharing'. In the list that appears, check the ‘Remote Login’ option.

Once you do that then you should be able to SSH

Comment: Yes, sshd is enabled. As I said, I can connect from localhost, so we know that sshd is running.